# use file php in python and use or print variable config

Tags: php, python, variables

i need use file config.php in python application, exemple file config.php :

```
define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

how can import this setting in python and use it ? how can extract username, password and host ?

Comment: Are you asking how to interpret a php file included in a python document?

Comment: yes, need extract data, exemple username, password and localhost, how can make this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make class *PhpConfig* where you will parse your data.

```
import re

class PhpConfig:
    def __init__(self, config_filename):
        self.defines = {}
        with open(config_filename) as infile:
            for ln in infile:
                match = re.findall('^define\(\'([A-Za-z_0-9]+)\', ?\'(.*)\'', ln)
                if len(match):
                    self.defines[match[0][0]] = match[0][1]

php_config = PhpConfig('config.php')

# Printing define dictionary
print(php_config.defines)

# Accessing just DB_USER
print(php_config.defines['DB_USER'])
```

Comment: You can also define it as static, so that it will not be parsed everytime you would like to access your config value. Just use your imagination, this is like a concept I would go further.

Comment: thanks so mach, bat if have data in variables how cand parse ? exemple = """ define('DB_USER', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');"" how can parse this variable ?

Comment: Oh, seems that your are newbie in python. Simply change the line "with open(..." with "infile = exemple.splitlines()" and move the whole block one indent to the left.